# C language script that will find the Zero-Input Response of a Second order LTI

Tags: c, math

The script is supposed to find the Zero-Input Response of a Second order Linear Time Invariant System D2y+a1Dy+a2 = 0 based on coefficients (a1 and a2 ) and initial conditions (y(0) and y’(0)).  (D=d/dt).

Based on the roots λ1 and λ2 of the second order system, your script should decide
a) If roots (λ’s)  are nonrepeating real , the response y(t) is
y(t) = C1 e λ1t+C2e λ2t, for t≥0.
Find C’s and display your y(t) on screen.
b) If roots (λ’s)  are repeating real (λ1 =λ2), the response y(t) is
y(t) = (C1 +C2t)eλt, for t≥0.
Find C’s and display your y(t) on screen.
c) If roots (λ’s)  are complex conjugate (λ’s  = α+jβ and α-jβ ), the response y(t) is
y(t)=Cαtcos(βt+θ), for t≥0.
Find C and θ and display your y(t) on screen.

Below is what I have tried, but my roots are coming back with a weird value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void roots( float a, float b, float* y1, float* y2 )
{
    float r = sqrt( a*a - 4*a*b) ;
    *y1 = (-a + r) / 2 ;
    *y2 = (-a - r) / 2 ;
}

int main()
{
    //declaring variables

    float a, b; //a is equivalent to coefficient a1 and b is equivalent to coefficient a2

    float D, y1, y2, k; //k is the given constant

    float i1, i2;

    D = (b*b)-(4*a*k);

    double root1, root2;

    /*D=d/dt or lambda; (y(0) and y'(0); x^2 + ax + b = 0 */

    //Asking for user input of coefficients
    printf("Enter the values for a1, a2, separated by a space: ");
    scanf("%f %f", &a, &b);

    //Asking user input of initial conditions; y(0)=? y'(0)=?
    printf("Enter two initial conditions separated by a space (y(0) and y'(0)): ");
    scanf("%f %f", &i1, &i2);

    printf("Value of Root 1: %f\n", root1 = (((-1)*(a)) + sqrt((pow(a,2)) - (4*a*b))) / (2));//positive root

    printf("Value of Root 2: %f\n", root2 = (((-1)*(a)) - sqrt( (pow(a,2)) - (4*a*b))) / (2));//negative root



return (0);
}
```